# Cannot access my ssrs server using my dns name on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS running on my Azure VM, I want to access my SSRS Server Portal through my DNS name with an https. I already deploy add configure my https using a certificate that I already generate using let's encrypt and a different port. FYI this certificate is used by my Website too. But when I try to access my SSRS using an https and my DNS name, but it won't connect, its return site can't be reached. I already add inbound rules to my port too. But when I try to connect from my Ip and Http It will connect. What did I miss? 
[image: rs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I need to add my Inbound port in my azure Network Security Group